# Maven AntRUn plugin propertiess

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I currently have a Jenkins Ant job that I'm trying to migrate to Maven. 
I'm usnig the antrun plugin which will allow me to call the existing ant script - and I'm happy with that.
The only issue I have is that it looks like antrun is unable to read values from parameter files in the same way Ant does ?

So for example in my ant build.xml I have a reference to a properties file :

```
<property file="${src.dir}/app.properties"/>
```

which contains a few properties files such as APP_NAME

When I run this via antrun ... ${src.dir} hasn't been populated and thus neither have the app.properties.

I have been able to get around this by using the property tab in the pom - but thats effectively hard coding :(

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<configuration>
<tasks>
<property name="env" value="TEST" />
<ant antfile="/opt/jenkins/test/DEPLOY/build.xml" target="deployApp"/>
</tasks>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to still reference the param files ?

Comment: Where is `${src.dir}` defined?

Comment: src.dir is a standard ant variable I believe. so it just defaults to where the ant is run from